# C++, forward declaration and recursive data types

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I would like to be able to have a map where the value is a pointer into the map. Something like

```
std::map<KeyType, const_pointer_to_this_map's_value_type>
```

I know I could use const void * instead of const_pointer_to_this_map's_value_type.

I've seen tricks for cyclic data type definitions, such as https://gist.github.com/tivtag/1208331 or http://qscribble.blogspot.fr/2008/06/circular-template-references-in-c.html but I am not sure if and how they can be applied to my case.

There they use their own classes (Vertex and Edge; A and B), but here std::map and std::map::value_type are already defined in the STL headers and I can't just instantiate them with the Combo class.

Is there a way to define the map above?

Comment: I detect an XY problem.  Why would you want such a thing?

Comment: Sounds like he's programming a directed graph where each node has one outgoing edge.

Comment: If you are trying to define graphs, use [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)

Comment: I can't recommend boost.graph.  I've used it in a project and imho it was more ugly than it was worth.  Ended up working around its limitations more than using any of its advantages.  Unless you're truly creating a set of generic graph algorithms, it's just not worth the pain.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a structure. You need to give a name to the type in order to be able to refer to it.

```
template<class T>
class Graph {
    std::map<T, const Graph<T>*> data;
public:
    // ...
};
```

In C++11 you can also do it with a template alias of a typedef with a forward declaration:

```
namespace {

template<class T>
struct GraphWrap {
    class type;
    typedef std::map<T, const typename GraphWrap<T>::type*> type;
};

}

template<class T>
using Graph = typename GraphWrap<T>::type;
```

Of course, using `std::map` here might be a bit misleading, because you’re using the key type parameter as the container’s value type. Like Mooing Duck said, you seem to be modelling a directed graph where each node has at most one outgoing edge. If you want to do something with graphs, there are graph libraries out there—if you’re doing something else, or if you just want to learn, then that’s another story.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I wanted. Here the mapped_type of the map is a pointer to the whole GraphWrapper. So all elements in the map will have the same value. I wanted something like typedef std::map<T, const typename GraphWrap<T>::type::value_type *> type;

Comment: You cannot declare a member type (or any type synonym) without defining it like you are attempting to do in the second snippet.

Comment: @user2521308: Oh, you wanted `T = const T*`? That’s how I initially read your question, but I discounted it because it’s an infinite type, which doesn’t really make sense.

Comment: @LucDanton: Thanks, I was unsure about that. There may be a bug in Clang (Apple’s version of 3.2), which seemed to accept it, but I was probably just careless.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html

> Map is a Pair Associative Container, meaning that its value type is `pair<const Key, Data>`

`std::map<K, M>::value_type` is always `std::pair<K, M>`, so:

```
#include <map>

typedef int KeyType;

struct MappedType
{
    const std::pair<const KeyType, MappedType>* p;
};

void g()
{
    std::map<KeyType, MappedType> m;

    m[0].p = 0;
    m[1].p = &(*m.find(0));
}
```